# Sentry.io API get issues filtering on environment tag

Tags: python, python-requests, sentry

I would like to retrieve the issues from sentry.io

The following code returns me the first page of the issues

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/my-account/my-project/issues/"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <token here>")
issues = json.loads(res.text)
```

I'm struggling to use the "query" mentioned in their (brief) documenation:
https://docs.sentry.io/api/events/list-a-projects-issues/

> query (string)
>
> An optional Sentry structured search query. If not provided an implied "is:unresolved" is assumed.

**Question:** How would I use `query` to filter for instance "environment" being equal "production"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mislead by the documentation. It's actually rather straight forward:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/my-account/my-project/issues/"
query_str = "environment=production"
res = requests.get(f"{url}?{query_str}", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <token here>")
issues = json.loads(res.text)
```

Comment: I did try this with a bunch of different requests/projects/environment we got and I get unexplicable results (some which aren't in the environment, etc.). This isn't working as expected, and isn't documented. Hopefully this evolves soon.

Answer (score 0):

With the current solution, I also got a different amount of issues than what I saw on the sentry dashboard, however I managed to fix this by just a very small correction by querying for `env` instead of `environment`, like:

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/my-account/my-project/issues/"
query_str = "env=production" # depends on how you name the env prod/production
res = requests.get(f"{url}?{query_str}", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer <token here>")
issues = json.loads(res.text)
```